# How can I include the parent folder structure on a library distribution in Python 3.6 using setuptools?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I am using setuptools to distribute a Python library. I have the following directory structure:

```
  /src
    /production
      setup.py
      /prod-library
        /package1
        /package2
```

The folder structure has to stay like this because there will be multiple libraries living under src in the future and need to have their own setup.py files. So the traditional answer of having 1 parent folder and moving out setup.py to the root folder will not work in this case.

I am using the following in the setup.py of the library to export the library (which is working)

```
    package_dir={'': '.'},
    packages=find_packages()
```

Inside the project tar.gz it looks like this:

```
    /prod-library
      /package1
      /package2
```

But inside the prod-library package Python files, imports referencing other modules need to be structured as follows:

```
    import src.production.prod-library.package1
    import src.production.prod-library.package2
```

The problem: 
After importing one of those libraries to a different project, errors are raised as follows:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.production'`

Since the build only drops in the /prod-library package, the project importing the code fails due to the missing folder structure (src/production) since the built distribution only has /prod-library.

What I need to do is include the src/production folder in the distribution build so the resulting tar.gz file looks like this:

```
   /src
     /production
       /prod-library
          /package1
          /package2
```

I am not sure how I can get those in the build structure since they are above the setup.py location. How can that be accomplished?

If it can’t, then I am open to suggestions about fixing the imports if that can be a solution.

Comment: Why not importing `import prod-library.package1` instead? To fix failing imports when developing, perform one-time install in development mode: `python src/production/setup.py develop` or, if you use `pip`, `pip install --editable src/production`. Usually, you should always do dev install if using `package_dir`. Also, the setup script is usually placed in the project root (unless you're developing multiple packages in one project).

Comment: When importing `import prod-library.package1` inside the packages, the files cannot be found since the directory structure is `src.production.prod-library.package1` and the setup.py file is referencing the '.' directory (current directory). 
Also, develop mode does not solve the problem here. The issue is the final  .egg file SOURCES.txt has file paths like this: "./prod-library.package1/subpackage/__init__.py". This is correct according to how the setup.py is structured but dont know how to fix the import problem. The setup script cannot be placed in the project root (see post comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It has to do with how the package_dir was configured:

```
    package_dir={'': '.'}
```

Although the above package_dir built the files and included all subfolders as expected, the egg-info file's SOURCES.txt was incorrect and showing as follows:

```
    ./prod-library/__init__.py
    ./prod-library/package1/__init__.py
    etc...
```

When the package was imported into another API, the imports could not be found when attempting import prod-libary.package1.file.py

After changing the package_dir as follows, I was able to use the library normally:

```
    package_dir={'.': ''}
```

The above effectively removed the ./ prefix in the SOURCES.txt file which was breaking the imports. Now the egg-info's SOURCES.txt looks correct:

```
    prod-library/__init__.py
    prod-library/package1/__init__.py
    etc...
```