# Template DataFlow with multiple Python dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a template DataFlow in Python from a pipeline with multiple files dependency.

This is the project structure:

```
root
|
----> project_dir
      |
      ----> __init__.py
      ----> main.py
      ----> setup.py
      utils
      |
      ----> functions.py
      ----> __init__.py
```

In the file main.py there is the import line:

```
from project_dir.utils.functions import something
```

And my setup.py file contains (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134019/how-can-i-include-the-parent-folder-structure-on-a-library-distribution-in-pytho) ):

```
package_dir={'.': ''},
packages=setuptools.find_packages()
```

The template file is generated with no problems, but everytime I try to execute it on DataFlow I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'project_dir'
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the utils directory in "root/utils" or "root/project_dir/utils"? The diagram makes it look like the first one, but your import implies the second one.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: @DarioB I've just posted the answer to the problem, hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I switched to the following structure:

```
root
|
----> project_dir
  |
  ----> __init__.py
  ----> main.py
  utils
  |
  ----> functions.py
  ----> __init__.py
  setup.py
  installment_requirements.txt
```

This is my setup.py file:

```
import setuptools

requires = [
    'google-cloud-storage==1.36.1',
    'pysftp==0.2.9'
]

setuptools.setup(
    name='name',
    version='0.0.1',
    install_requires=requires,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Then I create the template with a Cloudbuild that installs the requirements and executes the pipeline with template creation parameters:

```
steps:
  - name: 'python:3.8-slim'
    args: ['pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'pip']
    waitFor: ['-']
    id: 'upgrade-pip'
  - name: 'python:3.8-slim'
    args: ['pip', 'install', '-r', './installment_requirements.txt', '--user']
    waitFor: ['upgrade-pip']
    id: 'install-requirements'
  - name: 'python:3.8-slim'
    args: ["python", "./project_dir/main.py"]
    env: ['PYTHONPATH=./', 'DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}']
    waitFor: ['install-requirements']
    id: 'create-df-template
```

The file installment_requirements.txt is an export with pip freeze in order to get dependencies to be installed during the template creation.